# I want to enter the text if the dropdown list is empty in the spinner android

Tags: android

I Have to let an id be selected from a dropdown list of a spinner. If the list is empty I want to be able to enter id manually. How is this possible in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Spinner allows that and it's not a good solution anyway because phone screens are small.

You can create a ListView listing all the existing items with an 'Create New' item on the very top.

Or you can have a Plus icon in the Action Bar or a menu choice in the menu.

You may want to study Contacts application UI to see how they do it for adding a new contact

Comment: My requirement is when the list is empty only then I want to show editbox at same place as the spinner.

Comment: user1059747 Whoever created that requirement might want to reconsider after having investigated some existing Android apps. However, if that requirement is a must why not define both spinner and EditBox and make either one or another visible by calling setVisibility as needed

Comment: I tried that, but I was unable to place both spinner and edittext in same position.

Comment: Since they are different in sizes they will not occupy exactly the same area anyway. You can create a FrameLayout inside your main layout. Then you put both spinner and edittext in that FrameLayout. FrameLayouts are useful when we want to display one control only from a group of controls

Comment: Great, thanks I did not think of a frame layout. I shall try that.

Comment: One last thing I want to know is how do I check which view is visible?

Comment: You can use getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE

Comment: I got it i had to check if View.getVisibilty().